# How to bundle file folders with Ocra

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ocra

I would just like to know whether the following is possible:

My goal with creating a ruby executable was to be able to add some portability to my ruby script. What the script does is that it gathers some .txt files placed in a certain directory, and then processes them and outputs the .txt results in another file directory.

Without ocra this works fine with my script as I simply have my script search for a certain file folder name that is located in its present working directory, and process all the .txt placed within and output its results into another certain file folder.

My question is, can I have the final .exe file created by ocra do the same thing?

The current issue is is that when I run the following command:

```
ocra myscript.rb use_this_folder/
```

and then move the produced "myscript.exe" somewhere else where another copy of "use_this_folder" is located, it does not recognize that file folder.

At the top of my ruby script I have placed:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname($0)
Dir.chdir File.dirname($0)
```

Hopefully this all makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your program is having a difficult time finding the directory for your text files are in. I am guessing that your input and output folders are in relative folders to the exe file that you want to run. `Dir.chdir File.dirname($0)` gives you the temporary version of the exe file in your temp directory. Your program needs to know where the original exe is located. Where your exe is located is stored in this variable: `ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]`. Use this to change the working directory to the same directory that your exe is located:

```
Dir.chdir File.dirname(ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]) if ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]
```

For Example this script with the exe located in a folder name "MyProgram" in the root of a different drive:

```
Dir.chdir File.dirname($0)
p Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir File.dirname(ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]) if ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]
p Dir.pwd
```

outputs this when run by the exe file:

```
"C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/ocr7293.tmp/src"
"D:/MyProgram"
```

the `if ENV["OCRA_EXECUTABLE"]` is a bit of code asking whether or not to change the directory if it is an ocra exe file. Without the if statement the Environment variable is nil and `Dir.chdir` will throw an exception because it can't change directory to nil.

Little short on time but hope this helps. Good Luck.